# What is the limit of $f(a,b) = \frac{a^\beta}{a^2 + b^2}$ as $(a,b) \to (0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> What is the limit of $f(a,b) =\frac{a^\beta}{a^2 + b^2}$ as $(a,b) \to (0,0)$?

Clearly the answer depends on the value of $\beta$. For $\beta > 0$, we can deduce via inequalities that $\lim_{(a,b) \to (0,0)} f(a,b) = 0$.

However, for $\beta < 0$, the answer is less obvious. How would you approach this case?

Comment: You accepted an answer 53 minutes after it was posted; did this let you the time to check it thoroughly?

Comment: You modified without notification the question after some detailed answer to the original version of your question was posted. As a first consequence, the considerations in your post about $\beta>0$ vs $\beta<0$ are now absurd. As a second, more important, consequence, a posted answer became offtopic. After 3 years on the site and 100+ questions asked, such a behaviour is difficult to understand.

Comment: To explain, I've been creating different functions with $\beta$ to understand certain outcomes. As it happened, the answer to my original formulation didn't help my understanding. In retrospect, I see it's caused a mess and I should have asked a second question rather than done a modification (which I made because I didn't want to flood the site with similar questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will discuss the cases where $\beta$ is not an integer. To make it clearly, let's consider the limit$$\lim_{(a,b)\to(0,0),a>0}\frac{a^\beta}{a^2+b^2}.$$
For $\beta>2$, since $\left|\dfrac{a^\beta}{a^2+b^2}\right|=\left|\dfrac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}\right||a^{\beta-2}|<|a^{\beta-2}|$ , the limit is $0$.
For $0<\beta\le 2$, the limit doesn't exist, because the two iterated limits is not equal.
For $\beta\le 0$, the limit is $+\infty$, for the denominator tends to $+0$, and the numerator tends to $+\infty$ or $1$.

**Note**: If we suppose $\beta$ is integer, then we can consider the case where $a\le 0$. It is easy now to prove that when $\beta=-1, -3,\ldots$, the limit doesn't exist; in other cases the answer is the same as what I have discussed above.

Comment: For $\beta < 0$, how can you see the limit is $+\infty$? By substitution (e.g. $a=b^2$), I can see this is true for individual cases, but what is a comprehensive way to show it for all $(a,b) \to (0,0)$?

Comment: I didn't say the limit exist. I said the ITERATED limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: If $\beta<2$, then approach along the path $b=0$, and the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: "For $\beta>0$, your argument is valid." No it is not. Sorry.

Comment: @Did The function in the problem has been modified without notification. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Indeed the OP made a mess of this.

Comment: @EclipseSun Apologies. I've explained in the comments to the question. I will proceed with more consideration next time around.

Answer (score 0):

**Added: Assume $\beta$ is an integer.**

Case $1$: If $\beta > 2$, then the numerator is more dominant than the denominator, hence the limit of $f(a, b)$ when $(a, b) \rightarrow (0,0)$ is $0$.

Case $2$: If $\beta < 2$, then the denominator is more dominant than the numerator, and since $a^2 + b^2$ is always positive but $a^\beta$ can be positive or negative, hence there are $2$ cases:

- Case $2a$: When $\beta$ is even, $a^\beta$ is always positive. So the limit of $f(a, b)$ when $(a, b) \rightarrow (0,0)$ is $+\infty$.
- Case $2b$: When $\beta$ is odd, $a^\beta$ follows the sign of $a$. So the limit of $f(a, b)$ when $(a, b) \rightarrow (0,0)$ does not exist.

Case $3$: If $\beta = 2$, then when both $a$ and $b$ tend to $0$, we can substitute $b$ as $a$, and the function is reduced to $\frac{1}{2}$. In other words, the limit of $f(a, b)$ when $(a, b) \rightarrow (0,0)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Added**: If $\beta$ is not an integer, since $a^\beta$ is undefined when $a < 0$. Therefore the limit of $f(a, b)$ when $(a, b) \rightarrow (0,0)$ does not exist.